# PHP webservice file upload & download logic with Android client

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, web-services

First, this is my first time building both of webservice and android client at the same time, so please kindly help me. My goal is to be able to upload a file from android apps and download it from the webservice.

This is what i did for upload (working, but im **not** sure this is a best way) :

1. Convert the image to base64 String in android apps
2. Send that converted string (form image) to the webservice.
3. Decode that string with `base64_decode` function in the webservice.
4. Save the image from the decoded string, using `file_put_contents`.
5. Input the decoded string to the BLOB field in my database.

What make me confuse is, if i **already** saved the image file (step 4), do i still need to save it to the BLOB column (step 5)?

Now, i got confuse with the download part. This is what im planning to do :

1. Get the image file from step 4 in upload using `file_get_contents` (return string)
2. Send the result (string) to my android apps
3. Get the string and convert it to the image (**how?**)

Is it all i need to download?

Do i need to use `base64_decode` or `base64_encode` in download? When do i use it?

Sorry if my question sounds silly, i still dont get the logic.

Thanks a lot for your time, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What make me confuse is, if i already saved the image file (step 4), do i still need to save it to the BLOB column (step 5)?

No you don't. You can store in DB just a reference to that file, like filename or full path.

> Now, i got confuse with the download part. This is what im planning to do :
>
> 1. Get the image file from step 4 in upload using file_get_contents (return string)

and base64_encode it

> 3. Get the string and convert it to the image (how?)

You need to base64 decode it, because you encode it before sending it from the server. (step 1)

Comment: Thanks. So the way to download is just the reverse of upload? I will try your solution soon and let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: Exactly, you just reverse the "upload" process.